# Sketch Export SVG with integer values

Tags: svg, path, integer, rounding, sketchapp

When I export SVG from MAC Sketch App

I have 2 issues :

1) Remove unwanted tags

```
<!-- Generator: Sketch 40 (33762) - http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch -->
<title>Combined Shape</title>
<desc>Created with Sketch.</desc>
<defs></defs>
```

2) I need to export all paths rounding to the nearest integer and create the path.
It exports as :

```
<path d="M10,18.0000511 L10,18.0000511 Z"></path>
```

Set to export like below :

```
<path d="M10,18 L10,18 Z"></path>
```

Kindly help me with this

Comment: If Sketch can't do it, then you could run it through a tool like [svgo](https://github.com/svg/svgo).

Comment: I use https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/ which is awesome.